# Java multi threading executing more than the loop bounds

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am creating a web scraper to pull both links and emails from the web. The links will be used to find new places to search for emails and the emails will then be stored in a set. Each link is passed to a fixed thread pool in its own thread to look for more emails. I started of small only looking for 10 emails but for some reason my code returns about 13 emails.

```
    while (emailSet.size() <= EMAIL_MAX_COUNT) {

        link = linksToVisit.poll();

        linksToVisit.remove(link);
        linksVisited.add(link);
        pool.execute(new Scraper(link));
    }

    pool.shutdownNow();

    emailSet.stream().forEach((s) -> {
        System.out.println(s);
    });
    System.out.println(emailSet.size());
```

While I understand that it is possible to create extra threads that will still be running after I get 10 emails shouldn't `pool.shutdownNow()` end those threads?

Here is my Thread code if it helps.

```
class Scraper implements Runnable {

    private String link;

    Scraper(String s) {
        link = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(link).get();

            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element href : links) {
                String newLink = href.attr("abs:href");
                if (!linksVisited.contains(newLink) && !linksToVisit.contains(newLink)) {
                    linksToVisit.add(newLink);
                }
            }
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                    "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+");
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(doc.text());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                emailSet.add(matcher.group());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Catch on of the many exceptions Jsoup.connect might throw 
            // and just let the thread expire.
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

I should of included this my first time but I am using a thread safe set and queue.

```
Set<String> emailSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
BlockingQueue<String> linksToVisit = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10000);
Set<String> linksVisited = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
final int EMAIL_MAX_COUNT = 10;
ExecutorService pool = newFixedThreadPool(25);
```

Edit 2

Figured that I should update my question with the answer so here is where my problem was.

```
    while (emailSet.size() <= EMAIL_MAX_COUNT) {

    link = linksToVisit.poll();

    linksToVisit.remove(link);
    linksVisited.add(link);
    pool.execute(new Scraper(link));
}
```

My list would start off with only one link. After the first link was removed I had an empty list that kept creating new threads with no link to search through. Before the list could be populated I had already created hundreds of threads doing nothing but slowing down the system until it finally just crashed.

Here is the code fix to ensure no threads would be created if there was no link to search.

```
while (emailSet.size() <= EMAIL_MAX_COUNT) {

        if (linksToVisit.size() > 0) {
            link = linksToVisit.poll();

            linksToVisit.remove(link);
            linksVisited.add(link);
            pool.execute(new Scraper(link));
            //System.out.println("Emails " + emailSet.size());
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Crawler.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of EMAIL_MAX_COUNT ?

Comment: Why are you scraping the web for e-mail adresses?  I see potential evil here!

Comment: EMAIL_MAX_COUNT is 10.

Comment: If you're not synchronizing any of this, you have threads writing to emailSet while others are reading it's size. Let's look at a simple example with two Threads T1 and T2. T1 enters your critical section (the while loop) and reads size. It continues running. T2 enters the while loop and reads size before T1 adds. T2 then continues while T1 adds to the Set, which now contains 10 elements. However, T2 is already in the critical section and also adds an element, resulting in 11 elements. When this happens with more than 2 threads, bingo, arbitrary number above 10.

Comment: yeah on principal not going to help answering this ;)

Comment: Edited to show I am in synchronizing the code. Also this is a HW not trying to be evil. My teacher basically wants us to scrape all the emails associated with my school.

Comment: Using thread-safe collections alone doesn't automatically protect you from concurrency issues. The collections themselves only guarantee that any access to their data is safe. However, your logic needs to mirror your requirements and it's your job to make sure that the collections are used in the proper context.

Answer (score 1):

You start a scaper in asyncronous way inside a loop that checks the emailSet size, but during the duration of one cycle of the loop a scraper can find more than one email, or you can start more than one scraper and after you start it it adds alla the email links the page
Consider the following timing

```
T1 loop start ->T2 loop schedule Scaper ->T3 loop check emailSet ->T4 Scraper finds 13 email -> T5  loop check emailSet
```

or the following one

```
T1 loop start ->T2 loop schedule Scaper "1" ->T3 loop check emailSet ->T4 loop schedule Scaper "2" T5 -> Scraper "1" finds 6 emails -> T6  loop check emailSet -> Scraper "1" finds 7 emails
```

and so on.

If you want to stop when you find 10 emails you have to change the following one

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    emailSet.add(matcher.group());
}
```

to

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (emailSet.size() <= EMAIL_MAX_COUNT) {
        emailSet.add(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

and even this does not fully guarantee that you can stop at EMAIL_MAX_COUNT because with multiple threads (3 for example) can check the size and get 9 and then all them insert an email.

You must synchronize the read and write operation within a single block (with `synchronized(emailSet)` or using a Lock) if you want to ensure the exact emailSet size; something like

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    synchronized(emailSet) {
       if (emailSet.size() <= EMAIL_MAX_COUNT) {
           emailSet.add(matcher.group());
       }
    }
}
```